# Discord Webhook edit request returns 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: python, http, discord, webhooks

I am trying to edit a Discord webhook's message. I successfully did this once, then it didn't work. Here's my code:

```py
from urllib import request
from urllib import parse
text = open('readme.txt').read()
webhook_url = 'webhookURL'
msg_url = 'URL which contains the message'
def parser(data): #Parse the data to URL friendly
    return parse.urlencode(data).encode('ascii')
while True:
    if text != open('readme.txt').read():
        text = open('readme.txt').read()
        request.urlopen(request.Request(msg_url, parser({'content': text}), {'User-Agent': 'Python-Discord Interface'}, method='PATCH'))
```

What this should do is update the message when the file changes. This worked once, but it doesn't work anymore and instead returns 400 (Bad Request). I suspect you can only edit a message once, but Discord's documentation does not say that.
The links are checked and valid.

Comment: What's the webhook site you're using?

Comment: @isopach Discord